# Gijgo diplicate rendered icons on grid reload

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using Gijgo grid in inline mode and using render to show/update edit icons per row as below.

```
            var EditRenderer = function (value, record, $cell, $displayEl, id) {
               var ThisLine = Object.values(record)
               if (value == true || ThisLine.includes("Totals")){
                  null
               }
               else
               {
                   var $editBtn = $('<p class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil gj-cursor-pointer" data-key="' + id + '"></p>'),
                   $updateBtn = $('<p class="glyphicon glyphicon-save gj-cursor-pointer" data-key="' + id + '"></p>').hide();
                   $editBtn.on('click', function (e) {
                   grid.edit($(this).data('key'));
                   $editBtn.hide();
                   $updateBtn.show();
                });
                $updateBtn.on('click', function (e) {
                   grid.update($(this).data('key'));
                   $editBtn.show();
                   $updateBtn.hide();
                });
            }
            $displayEl.append($editBtn).append($updateBtn);
```

I am dynamically generating the columns but the bottoms are added to the grid as below.

```
   GridColumns.push({ field: 'JobClossedForEdit', title: '', width: 35, align: 'center',  renderer: EditRenderer })
   GridColumns.push({ field: 'JobClossedForEdit', title: '', width: 35, align: 'center',  renderer: DeleteRenderer })
```

My grid is setup as below:

```
        grid = $('#grid').grid({
            dataSource: '/TimeSheets/IndexGetGrid?UserId=' + @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.UserId)) + "&sortOrder=" + @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.JobNumberSortParm))  + "&monthFilter=" + @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.monthFilter(2))) + "&yearFilter=" + @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.yearFilter(2))),
            uiLibrary: 'bootstrap',
            primaryKey: 'Id',
            iconsLibrary: 'glyphicons', //fontawesome
            inlineEditing: { mode: 'command', managementColumn: false },
            columns: GridColumns,
        });
```

When the save bottom is clicked the below runs.

```
         grid.on('rowDataChanged', function (e, id, record) {
            var data = $.extend(true, {}, record);
            $.ajax({ url: '/TimeSheets/IndexSaveGrid', data: { record: data }, method: 'POST' })
                .fail(function () {
                    alert('Failed to save.');
                });
            grid.reload();
        });
```

So the problem is that when `grid.reload()` is fired, `$displayEl.append($editBtn).append($updateBtn);` runs, adding a second set of edit icons to the grid.

I have tried everything I know (very limited knowledge!!) e.g. hide/delete/destroy any elements involved before the `.append` with no luck, I am a bit stuck!

Any help/pointers welcome
Thanks,
Richard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds simple.. in the end I added `grid.clear();` before `grid.reload();`. Dont like it as a solution as I dont see this as being necessary, but it works...

Full Code;

```
    grid.on('rowDataChanged', function (e, id, record) {
        var data = $.extend(true, {}, record);
        $.ajax({ url: '/TimeSheets/IndexSaveGrid', data: { record: data }, method: 'POST' })
            .fail(function () {
                alert('Failed to save.');
            });
        grid.clear(); <-----Addded------
        grid.reload();
    });
```